# S3 bucket next js access privately the images

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, next.js

I want to access the images from a private bucket not a public one the code below is simple example of what I am doing to access the images but I think it should not be the case and there is a way to access a private bucket easily without having to make everything public in the bucket in the api file I use `ACL:"public-read"` to make it public even uploaded the image with 2 fucntions `getSignedUrlPromise` and `createPresignedPost`

```js
import { Image } from "@material-ui/icons";
import Head from "next/head";
import axios from "axios";
import { useState } from "react";
import { server } from "../config";

export default function Test() {
  const [Urlfile, setUrlfile] = useState();
  const [file, setfile] = useState();
  const [UrlfileUpoaded, setUrlfileUploaded] = useState();
  const handleUpload = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const bucketURL = "https://blaketrade.s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/";
    const res = await fetch(`${server}/api/admin/add/addImage`, {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify({
        type: file.type,
        name: file.name,
      }),
    });

    const { url } = await res.json();

    await fetch(url, {
      method: "PUT",
      body: file,
      headers: {
        "Content-type": file.type,
      },
    });

    setUrlfileUploaded(bucketURL+file.name);
  };

  const fileSelectedHandler = (e) => {
    if (e?.target?.files[0]) {
      setfile(e.target.files[0]);
      setUrlfile(URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0]));
    }
  };
  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <title>Blake Trade</title>
        <link rel="icon" href="/logo_white.webp" />
      </Head>

      <div>
        <img src={Urlfile}></img>
        <br></br>
        <input type="file" onChange={fileSelectedHandler}></input>
        {file ? (
          <button onClick={handleUpload}> Upload</button>
        ) : (
          <button disabled onClick={handleUpload}>
            {" "}
            Upload
          </button>
        )}
        {UrlfileUpoaded ? <img src={UrlfileUpoaded}></img> : null}
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

and from the server side api file

```js
import aws from "aws-sdk";

export default async function handler(req, res) {

  aws.config.update({
      accessKeyId: "",
      secretAccessKey: "",
      region: "",
      signatureVersion: 'v4',
    });
  const s3 = new aws.S3();

  const { type, name } = JSON.parse(req.body);
  const filePrams = {
    Bucket: "bucketname",
    Key: name,
    Expires: 600,
    ContentType: type,
    ACL:"public-read",
  };
  console.log(filePrams);
  const url = await s3.getSignedUrlPromise("putObject", filePrams);
  console.log(url);
  res.status(200).json( {url} );
}
```

the problem is this work fine if the bucket is public but I don't think that it should be the case how to get the images to run from my url not amazon aws

is there a way to get the bucket to be accessed directly from my website and to be a private bucket

Comment: Access privately from where? Ec2 instance, or front-end of your website over the internet?

Comment: access front end on my website

Comment: How did it go? The issue still persists?

Answer (score 1):

There are **two options** which you can consider for accessing images in a **non-public** bucket at your front-end.

1. Use S3 [pre-signed urls](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html). In this case, each image would need to have generated such an url, for example by your backend. The url are temporary, so they need to be generated when needed or on periodical basis.
2. Setup [CouldFront distro](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/amazon-s3-amazon-cloudfront-a-match-made-in-the-cloud/) in front of your S3 bucket, and link to images using the distro. This not only ensures that your bucket is private, but also improves latency as your images would be cached in AWS Edge locations.

Comment: ok pre signed url access expires so that will not work as needed second one I have to look into it thanks

Comment: in ruby there is a active storage that show the link as it is on the same web even though it is on the bucket can we do that with react

Comment: @MohammadItani don't now. My answer is specific to aws, and independent of ruby or nodejs